# What does hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering means in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am learning Haskell and I would like to know what does `hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering` mean and if there are other commands of this style in Haskell.

Comment: Are you sure it's  `stdin` and not `stdout`? Also see the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hSetBuffering).

Answer (score 3):

The `LineBuffering` mode for `stdin` will prevent the application from processing the input until `end-of-line` character is encountered. Basically, it means, your app won't see the characters until you hit `Return`. Usually, this is the default mode for Terminal input. The other two are `NoBuffering` and `BlockBuffering`.

See this answer for more details: [Haskell default io buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520885/haskell-default-io-buffering)

Why do we need buffering? Buffering enables for more efficiently processing data. Instead of feeding the input one byte at a time, it is more efficient to do that in blocks. For Terminal input, the most natural size is one line at a time, because this is how usually an interactive command line application work: consume a line, process it, and present some response.

Some useful info here: http://wcipeg.com/wiki/I/O_buffering

Here is more involved explanation: https://www.quora.com/In-C-what-does-buffering-I-O-or-buffered-I-O-mean